# multiple binaries with same name in ubuntu/linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have recently installed a webframework play (http://www.playframework.com/) and want to have the play executable in the system path ie $PATH. But ubuntu already defines a command called play. How do I overwrite the system defined command with my framework binary path so that command play on commandline calls my framework rather than the old application.

Installation: I downloaded zipped file of the framework and upzipped in one of my personal folder which contains the docs and the executable.

Comment: what framework is it, can you supply more info how you installed?

Comment: put the directory where `play` from the framework is before the directory where the system's `play` is in the PATH directory list. in other words, PATH is searched sequential and the first matching command is used.

Comment: @Oz123 added the details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure you'll never use the original play command, you could just remove the binary. But in general, this isn't a good idea, since some system component you don't think of might need it, and the next update will probably restore it.

The best thing to do is to prepend the directory of your `play` command to the PATH, for example, using `PATH=/opt/framework/bin:$PATH` in your .profile (assuming your play command installs to `/opt/framework/bin/play`), or the script that starts your web server, or wherever you need your `play` command.

Remember that does *not* make your play command global. A common mistake is to add the path in their .profile file, then call the program from crontab - crontab scripts will not execute .profile or .bashrc.

Answer (score 1):

Never alter the contents of installed packages. Such changes can provoke hard to find problems in the system and anyway, they will most likely be overwritten again in subsequent updates. There are other alternatives:

1. obviously you can chose another name for your executable
2. place the executable in another part of your `$PATH` if its a "personal installation", typically `~/bin` is used for such approach. Remember that the order of entries in the `$PATH` variable is important, first come first serve.
3. use the traditional `/usr/local/bin` location for locally added "wild" installations, this way there is some form of clean separation between clean packages and wild installed files inside the system
4. store your software in some other location and prepend that to your personal or system wide `$PATH` variable
5. store your executable under another name and create an `alias` (see `man alias` for an explanation) for it which allows to call it by some name that "hides" the original command this way. For this the executable can be addressed with an absolute path, so it dies *not* have to be found inside the `$PATH` variable.

In my personal opinion options 2. and 5. and the best if it comes to "personal installations".